# iPython Notebook/Jupyter not actually saving

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, save, ipython, autosave

Saving my work does actually nothing.

I ran into this issue today. I was doing new work on an existing jupyter notebook with my laptop. I was opening and closing the laptop a few times (putting it in standby mode). When waking it up again, I could continue my work without problem. Autosave saved my work frequently, and I also saved it manually every now and then, or so I thought...

At the end of today the kernel had some issues where my notebooks wouldnt connect every time. Thus, I restarted the kernel and jupyter a few times. Every time I had to close jupyter, I also refreshed, sometimes closed and opened back up the notebook again. All no problem.

It was only now, that when I shut down everything completely, including my browser, and starting jupyter anew, NOTHING was actually saved.

I lost a good 8hrs of work today because of a software bug. Is there any other python environment that is good and easy to use? Because i think Jupyter might not be for me.

Comment: What version where you using of Anaconda? I encountered this issue when using version 2020.02. I've been using Anaconda Jupyter Notebook for years, and only today has this issue occurred.